# How to correctly reference a pointer within a struct using a double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, binary-search-tree, double-pointer

I'm trying to create a linked list where each ListNode contains a binary search tree within it.  Here are the structures:

```
typedef struct TreeNode {
   int label;
   long count;
   struct TreeNode *left;
   struct TreeNode *right;
} TreeNode;

typedef struct ListNode {
   TreeNode *ptr;
   struct ListNode *next;
   struct ListNode *prev;
} ListNode;
```

I have a function called addNode which adds the ListNodes in order based upon comparisons between the TreeNode's `label` and `count` values, however I can't figure out how to correctly compare them.

I keep getting the error: `request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union`

Referring to the second if statement in addNode:

```
void addNode(ListNode ** head, ListNode * new){

if(*head == NULL){
  *head = new;
  return;
}

if((*head -> next ->  ptr -> count) < (new -> ptr -> count)){
  addNode(&(*head -> next), new);
}
```

Could someone please explain the proper way to do this comparison?

Comment: You really shouldn't use "new" as a variable name: it's a C++ keyword and may trip up your C compiler.  It's possible the parser is having problems with that

Comment: probably something with the *head -> next that defers head first (and then getting a structure to work with rather than a pointer)

Comment: Why would a C++ keyword mess with the C compiler?  Is it because the languages are fairly similar?  (I don't know much about C++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `->` operator has higher precedence than the unary `*` operator.  So when  you do this:

```
*head->next
```

You're actually saying:

```
*(head->next)
```

You need to add some parenthesis:

```
if(((*head) -> next ->  ptr -> count) < (new -> ptr -> count)){
  addNode(&((*head) -> next), new);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that.